# RESTful way of allowing creation of a resource in multiple ways?

Tags: rest

Usually I use http `POST` request to create a new resource. For example you could've a `book` model and API as following:

**Model**

```js
interface Book{
  isbn: string, // primary key
  title: string,
  author: string,
  rating: number,
}
```

**API**

```
GET api/books            -> get all books
GET api/books/{isbn}     -> get one book by isbn
POST api/books/          -> create new books
PATCH api/books/{isbn}   -> update existing book by isbn
// and more..
```

A book can only be stored if there is an `isbn`, a `title` and a `author` for the book.

Now there are two clients which have different informations available when they want to create a new book item. E.g. the first client only knows the isbn while the second client has `isbn`, `title` and `author` available.

The backend has access to a private API where it can fetch details like `title` and `author` for a given `isbn`. Both clients don't have access to this API.

The first client can just create a new book item using the `POST api/books/` endoint since it has all mandatory information available. The question is how the second client should create a new item.

There are two options I currently have in mind:

1. Just send the `isbn` to the `POST api/books/` and the backend automatically fetches the `title` and `author` from the private API. Then it stores all of it as a new item in the database
2. The API exposes a new endpoint `GET api/books/{isbn}/info` where the backend calls the private API and returns the information - including `title` and author - back to the client. Then the client can do a `POST api/books/` request just as the first client to create a new book item.

**Question**

Is one of the above options actually RESTful?
Is there a best practice when it comes to RESTful API design for such a use case?

Comment: How would you do it on the Web? I could think of a form that the server provides to the clients that defines title and author as optional fields. A client having all of the information available can provide them to the server, a client not having them will ignore those optional ones and just send the mandatory information. This is also what HATEOAS is as clients use the hypermedia to drive the workflow while sticking to a more or less standardized representation format

Comment: So bascially option 1.? (Just FYI: in my case the first client is actually another backend while the second client is frontend, where the user would just have to provide the `isbn` for simplicity)